# NodeJS winston log file not change upon size limit

Tags: node.js, winston

I'm using [Winston](https://github.com/flatiron/winston/) logging and have specified file size to be max 10MB.

```
{
    filename: 'e:\app.log', 
    json:false, 
    maxsize:'10MB', 
    maxFiles:'10', 
    timestamp:true, 
    level:'silly'
}
```

I'm expecting the app.log file to be rotated upon size reaching 10MB, but this has never happened and my log file grows to even GBs.

Is there something I'm doing wrongly?　Thanks.

Comment: looks like you might need to either pass an absolute path for the `filename` or set a `dirname` according to this somewhat old [github issue](https://github.com/flatiron/winston/issues/90).

Comment: Go-oleg, thanks. In fact, in my code, it is absolute path. Re-updated my question.

Comment: I believe the value for `maxsize` should be in bytes, so you could try `10000000` instead of `'10MB'`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/docs/transports.md) the `maxsize`  must be in `bytes` so change it for `10000000`

Comment: the file is not rotating after reach the 'maxsize'.
I'm using "winston": "^2.3.1"

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: @KetavChotaliya maybe you can open another  question.

Answer (score 0):

Use **maxSize** instead of **maxsize** it will work.

Comment: Thx, I tried, but the property only applies on File Size, the entry (message) size could be greater than it.

Comment: @Varun even when i add maxSize the log file is going way behind the size. I am giving 100MB but the files are exceeding 200Mb .

Answer (score 0):

I think maxSize applies only for the file.

But before write inside it the Log Entry Size could be greater than the limit.

My question is if there are something similar like maxEntrySize to limit the log entry size directly, not only file size.